# Butchered Morse Code

Tags: knowledge, cipher, poetry

The space-eater has eaten up all the spaces from the following Morse encoded message. The message contains a quote by a famous person. Can you reconstruct the sentence?

> $....-..-.-.---......-.--......-...$
>   $-.....-..---.----..---.....--$
>   $-.----....-..-.-.------..$
>   $..........-$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's

> EVERYTHING HAS BEAUTY, BUT NOT EVERYONE SEES IT

Which is a quote attributed to

> Confucius

Properly delimited, this would read

> `. ...- . .-. -.-- - .... .. -. --. / .... .- ... / -... . .- ..- - -.-- --..-- / -... ..- - / -. --- - / . ...- . .-. -.-- --- -. . / ... . . ... / .. -`